# How to launch and receive output from another app through intent in react native?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-intent

I have create react native application using VSCode and now, I have to integrate the reader device using micro USB host.

I have install the reader app to test the APK. And based from the web, I can call the reader app through intent from my current app. Device weblink [here](http://www.causalidea.com/home/ci-showkad).

Currently, I have try search tutorial for calling native app through intent. But I'm stuck in a way to put the script. Either I should create new file/paste the script below existing/replace the existing in `./android/app/src/main/java/com/myAppName/MainApplication.java` and how to call and receive the output from my scanner class in `./src/screens/scanScreens/mainScanner.js`

Below is what I have go though but stuck on what should I do next:-

1. [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content)
2. [Integration of React-Native Module into an existing Native App (Android)](https://medium.com/@vibhor.vibhu/integration-of-react-native-module-into-an-existing-native-app-android-ded2b9ede83a)
3. [App-to-app communication with React Native on Android](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2018/04/04/app-app-communication-react-native-android/)
4. [Stack accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47012978/3436326)
5. [react-native-intent-launcher](https://github.com/poberwong/react-native-intent-launcher)

My current MainActivity.java **[UPDATED]**

```
package com.myappname;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "myAppName";
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
        @Override
        protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
        return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
        }
        };
    }
}
public class ShowKadModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    @ReactMethod
    public void showKadApp() {
        final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        Intent intent = new Intent ("com.causalidea.cikad.showkad.READ_MYKAD");
        Bundle extras = new Bundle ();
        extras.putBoolean ("READ_PHOTO", false); // Do not read the photo
        intent.putExtras (extras);
        activity.startActivityForResult (intent, 0); 
     }
     public ShowKadModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        // Add the listener for `onActivityResult`
        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener);
      }

      @Override
      public String getName() {
        return "ShowKadModule";
      }
     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            extras = intent.getExtras ();

            if (extras != null) {
                extras.getString ("IC_NUMBER");
                extras.getString ("NAME");
                extras.getString ("GENDER");
                extras.getString ("CITIZENSHIP");

                extras.getString ("BIRTH_DATE");
                extras.getString ("RACE");
                extras.getString ("RELIGION");

                extras.getString ("ADDRESS_1");
                extras.getString ("ADDRESS_2");
                extras.getString ("ADDRESS_3");
                extras.getString ("POSTCODE");
                extras.getString ("CITY");
                extras.getString ("STATE");

                photoByteArray = extras.getByteArray ("PHOTO");

                if (photoByteArray != null) {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (photoByteArray, 0, photoByteArray.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap (bitmap);
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: use broadcasts : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After go through so many example and tutorial, I have found a simple solutions. By installing react-native-activity-result from here.

How I perform this is as below:

```
import ActivityResult from 'react-native-activity-result';

_onLaunch = async () => {
    const activity = await ActivityResult.resolveActivity('com.causalidea.cikad.showkad.READ_MYKAD');
    if (!activity) {
        console.warn('Please install the othe app.');
        ToastAndroid.show(`MyKAD application reader is not install`, ToastAndroid.SHORT, ToastAndroid.BOTTOM);
    } else {
        console.log(`Activity will be handled by ${activity.package}`);
        ToastAndroid.show(`Activity will be handled by ${activity.package}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT, ToastAndroid.BOTTOM);
    }

    // Start an activity for a result
    let uniqueId = 0;
    let args = {READ_PHOTO: false};
    ToastAndroid.show(`Test`, ToastAndroid.SHORT, ToastAndroid.BOTTOM);
    const response = await ActivityResult.startActivityForResult(uniqueId, 'com.causalidea.cikad.showkad.READ_MYKAD', args);
    ToastAndroid.show(`Result code: ${response.resultCode}`, ToastAndroid.LONG, ToastAndroid.BOTTOM);


    if (response.resultCode !== ActivityResult.OK) {
        ToastAndroid.show(`Invalid result from activity.`, ToastAndroid.SHORT, ToastAndroid.BOTTOM);
        throw new Error('Invalid result from activity.');
    } else {
        console.log('Got the following response: ' + response.data);
        ToastAndroid.show(`Response:\n${JSON.stringify(response)}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT, ToastAndroid.BOTTOM);
    }

    // Finish an activity with a result. This will close the caller too.
    //ActivityResult.finish(ActivityResult.OK, 'com.causalidea.cikad.showkad.READ_MYKAD', args);
}
```

I can launch the other app and wait for activity result and it act as accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally, this Worked for me!**

I used this to share text/plain to my React Native application from other mobile applications.

AndroidManifest.xml :
*/myapp/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
 </intent-filter>
```

MainActivity.java - get Intent and share with React Native
*/myapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/webcontainer/MainActivity.java*

```
package com.myapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

   private boolean isReactContextInitialized = false;
   private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

   @Override
   protected String getMainComponentName() {
       return "myapp";
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = getReactInstanceManager();
       reactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext reactContext) {
               isReactContextInitialized = true;
               handleSharedTextIfNeeded(getIntent());
                  
                // Clear the intent to avoid processing it again
               setIntent(new Intent());
           }
       });    
   }

   @Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    handleSharedTextIfNeeded(intent);
}

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();     

       ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = getReactInstanceManager();
       reactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext reactContext) {
               isReactContextInitialized = true;
               Intent intent = getIntent();
               handleSharedTextIfNeeded(intent);
      
               // Clear the intent to avoid processing it again
               setIntent(new Intent());
           }
       });
   }
    
   private void handleSharedTextIfNeeded(Intent intent) {
       String action = intent.getAction();
       String type = intent.getType();

       if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
           String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
           if (sharedText != null) {
                           
               if (isReactContextInitialized) {
                   sendSharedTextToReactNative(sharedText);
                   handleSharedText(sharedText);
               } else {
                   // ReactContext is not initialized yet, handle it when initialized
                   handler.post(() -> {
                       sendSharedTextToReactNative(sharedText);
                       handleSharedText(sharedText);
                   });
               }
           }
       }
   }

   private void sendSharedTextToReactNative(String sharedText) {

       ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = getReactInstanceManager();
       ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();

       if (reactContext != null) {
            reactContext
           .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                   .emit("onSharedTextReceived", sharedText);
       } else {
           // Handle the case where the ReactContext is not available
       }
   }

   private void handleSharedText(String sharedText) {
       // Add your logic here to process the shared text in native code
   }
}
```

App.js - Receive Intent from Native in your React Native
*/myapp/App.js*

```
import {DeviceEventEmitter} from 'react-native';

  useEffect(() => {
    // Listen to the event for shared data
    const eventListener = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
      'onSharedTextReceived',
      data => {
        console.log('Received Data>>', data);
      },
    );

    // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      eventListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```