# Call an intent of another app from react native (error compiling react-native-activity-result)

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-studio, npm

I am trying to create an application which can launch a third party apk from react native and call an intent.

After doing some research the only react native package I could find which can achieve this is 'react-native-activity-result' which i found from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370210/how-to-launch-and-receive-output-from-another-app-through-intent-in-react-native) but I am unable to compile or use this package as some of the functionality has been depreciated.

I have tried with react-native-activity-result but I am getting errors while trying to compile it as it seems it is no longer maintained.

```
'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

e: C:\Users\user\scripts\intent\rntest\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (29, 33): Unresolved reference: replaceFirstChar
e: C:\Users\user\scripts\intent\rntest\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (29, 52): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\user\scripts\intent\rntest\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (253, 16): Unresolved reference: lowercase
e: C:\Users\user\scripts\intent\rntest\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\utils\Os.kt: (13, 38): Unresolved reference: lowercase
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

using gradle 6.9.1

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

If it is possible to compile this package I think I can achieve what I am trying to do but I am also open to suggestions on other packages

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.